# relative path resources from JS with HTML imports

Tags: polymer, web-component

I've got a (Polymer) web component that I want to make accessible to people in a cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) fashion.  That works fine except I'm not sure how I can give a relative path for resources like images and JSON files from JS code inside that component. They are interpreted as relative to the containing page, not relative to the HTML import. What I *think* I want is a JS variable that gives the path of the containing html file that was imported.  A relative path is important because I also want people to be able to easily deploy this to their own site and not rely on a hardcoded path to my copy of a resource.

For example, you load index.html at example.com and it has:

```
<link rel="import" href="//my-site.com/components/my-component/my-component.html">

<my-component> ... </my-component>
```

Now inside `my-component.html`, I have some JS that loads some resources based on the user's profile - images and JSON language files for i18next.js. The problem is that unless I specify them as an absolute path to `my-site.com`, which I don't want to do, they will be interpreted as relative to the page at `example.com/index.html`, not relative to the path of `my-component.html`

Any images that I specify statically in my template work fine and load correctly because it's relative to the HTML Import path.  I'm just not sure how to do this for resources loaded from JS because they will be relative to the containing page (example.com/index.html).  Is there an attribute or function somewhere that exposes this import path? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To create relative paths you can use the `resolvePath` method of your Polymer element. [Here's the docs on it](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/polymer/polymer.html#resolvepath)

ex: `this.resolvePath('x-foo.png')`

Update: `resolvePath` is replaced with `resolveUrl` for [Polymer 1.0](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/api/Polymer.Base#method-resolveUrl)

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for. I had read that document, or so I thought, but I must have missed that.

Comment: No worries, there's a ton of stuff in the docs so it's easy to overlook :)

Comment: @robdodson Could you please, please provide an example in the [Polymer docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/polymer/polymer.html#resolvepath)?

Comment: "[The resolvePath method in 0.5 is replaced by resolveUrl](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/migration.html#element-methods-mdash-resolvepath-renamed-to-resolveurl)". [1.0 documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/utility-functions.html).

Answer (score 1):

I found out that you can access the URL of the import from within a script inside it with `document.currentScript.baseURI`. I'm doing something like this:

```
<script>
    (function () {
        var srcURL = new window.URL(document.currentScript.baseURI);
        var baseURL = srcURL.origin + srcURL.pathname.substr(0, srcURL.pathname.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);

        // can use baseURL here to load resources
        Polymer({...});
    })();
</script>
```

One problem: the code above isn't working when I vulcanize everything because the paths change. I'll look into that one a bit later.

Comment: It might be worth taking a look at this issue re: vulcanize and assetPath (https://github.com/Polymer/vulcanize/issues/51)

Comment: Vulcanization is gone with Polymer 2, so you might luck out.