# HTML relative path to image. Cannot find 404 on Github Page

Tags: javascript, html, image, url, github-pages

I have the following file structure

```
demo  
|_ assets  
.....|_ image.png  
.....|_ anotherimage.png  
|_ dist  
.....|_ my-component.html  
.....|_ my-component.js  
|_ index.html
```

`my-component.html` have `<img src="../assets/image.png"/>`.
`my-component.js` generate `<img src="../assets/anotherimage.png">` HTML tag in run time.

This works fine in my local http server.
The problem occurs when I pushed the things to Github Page.

- Image as referred to inside `my-component.html` file are showed properly. It recognizes the image url as `http://myorg.github.io/myrepo/demo/assets/image.png`.
- It's 404 not found for image as referred to in `my-component.js` file. It recognizes the image url as `http://myorg.github.io/myrepo/assets/anotherimage.png`

**Notice** the url for both case that the browser recognizes. There's no `demo/` for second case.

It is like `my-component.js` is placed at `demo` directory instead of `dist`. But how that could happen. What's the problem here? and How can I fix it?

**Edited**
`my-component.html` and `my-component.js` in question are actually Polymer component splitting into 2 files one for template, and another for logic code.
Then `index.html` imports in that component via `<link rel="import" href="dist/my-component.html">` at the top of its code. There's no issue about Polymer or whatsoever I tested it before and I don't think the problem involves Polymer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WebComponents, the paths are relative to the HTML page, in Polymer, they are relative to the component itself. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/33603356/227299

A [possible solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29050862/227299) is to create your path using [`this.resolveUrl('../assets/image.png')`](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/migration#element-methods-mdash-resolvepath-renamed-to-resolveurl), relative to the JS file.

Comment: Javascript file will be included in that HTML file only and only one place. I would like to go with your suggested option 1, but as it works on others testing not on github page. Do you mean the fix is only for github page right?

Comment: That's weird as both files are in the same directory. And hey Juan, I've edited the question with more information. I'm not sure it can give more hint. Please see my edited question.

Comment: Thank you so much Juan. That helps a lot! Please kindly proceed to close down my question as answer was already there.